# How can I load into a pandas DataFrame tweets from a json file?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read my [Twitter data saved in json format](https://ufile.io/kjxt9) using the following code:

```
import json

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(tweet)
```

This code reads only one tweet and it works, but when I'm trying to read all file by:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
```

I receive an error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

What should I change to read this file properly?

My main task is to find creation dates for those tweets and I found it using following filters (I just used one tweet which worked at the beginning):

```
df2 = df[["user"]]
df3 = df2.loc[['created_at']]
df3
```

Is there a better way than DataFrames to handle this data?

Answer (score 2):

A more succint way to read in (all) your JSON file for me looks like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("python.json", orient = 'records', lines = True)
```

You can then apply transformations to `df` so to get data from the columns that you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried at the beginning in different combinations, but I still receive error: "ValueError: Expected object or value" or 'ValueError: Trailing data' when I use only f = pd.read_json("python.json").

Comment: as for the Expected object... error, is the file path / file name specified in the `read_json` command correct? As for the Trailing data error, are you specifying `orient` and `lines`? I'm asking because I was able to download and read in your file fine with the syntax above.

Comment: Path has to be correct, because I'm able to open other files in different formats. Trailing data occurs when I delete orient and lines.

Comment: are you able to save this data frame to csv format and upload here? I'd like to check if I have a problem with jsons generally, with this file or with something different?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
#results is the JSON tweet data. 

#Define the columns you want to extract
resultFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=["username","created_at","tweet"])
print len(results)

for i in range(len(results)):
    resultFrame.loc[i,"username"] = results[i].user.screen_name
    resultFrame.loc[i, "created_at"] = results[i].created_at
    resultFrame.loc[i, "tweet"] = results[i].text

print resultFrame.head()
```